# Python myro module importerror

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, module, myro

I am completely new in Python. Installed just today in school purposes. I need to use myro module but I am getting this error `ImportError: No module named 'myro'` all the time. I've found out that I have installed older versions of Python already with another software like Blender or Gimp. I am using 3.4.0 version for mac. How can I get this myro module? I've downloaded zipped files from http://myro.roboteducation.org/download/ but I don't know where to copy them. In Library/Python path are just these older versions (2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7). There isn't the latest version I just installed. Anybody who could help me please?

/edit. Well basically I need to be able to do some simple graphics in Python and the myro module is what I've found in youtube tutorial. But that's from 2010. Maybe there is something else today what makes graphics possible in Python 3.4.0. Anybody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute easiest thing to do in this situation is to go to [this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) and install Python Setuptools. [Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#unix-including-mac-os-x-curl) are the installation instructions for OSX. From there you can use `easy_install` and get `pip` from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/). Now all you have to do whenever you want to install a module you can:

```
pip install myro
```

I know it seems like a lot just for `myro` but you'll thank yourself for doing it when you want to get more serious with Python.

Now for your graphics needs.

**EDIT**:
Update link to [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.4.0)

There are quite a few packages for dealing with graphics but I like Pillow.

**EDIT**:
Installing setuptools:

1. Open your Terminal (I don't use Macs but I think you get there using Finder)
2. type the following command:

   curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python34

Then you should be all set. If you don't have `curl` then that's another can of worms.

Comment: Can I install these packages same as myro as you described above?

Comment: PIL is completely outdated, you want the latest version of Pillow (which is 2.4.0, BTW, not 1.7.7).

Comment: Absolutely! If it isn't on PyPi or you can't `pip install` `easy_install` usually will work if you can get the package's .egg file. Manual installation is usually a last resort.

Comment: @TomasJ yes, you can, just run `pip install Pillow` and you'll be all set.

Comment: I am really confused about installing setuptools. Can somebody please explain me more detail how to do that?

Comment: Ok so I installed setuptools by using terminal. But it's installed into Library/Python/2.7/... and that's not the version I am using. I am normaly working in Python shell not in terminal.

Comment: Now I see there was error during installing setuptools. I can't create or remove files in install directory which is /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Comment: Tried already - even more errors. But I solved this out by deleting all the other versions and reinstalling python. Now by following your help is all good. Thank you very much!